# Amazon S3 upload file and get URL in Unity3d

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/s3.html (Upload an Object) to upload an Image.

I am unable to get the uploaded object link(Location) in response.

In my case I need to upload an Image and get the uploaded file URL after upload success.

How can I get uploaded object URL?

In some resource I searched they suggested to use `s3Client.getResourceUrl("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg");` but I am unable to find that `getResourceUrl` method for `Client` in the example I am following.